# How to fetch the nested object data (id inside id)

Tags: javascript, object, rest

I'm trying to fetch the **name** of **item** which is inside **items** object, But maybe because of the **id** in-between those two I'm unable to do so.

I followed many previous anwwers here but couldn't find any help from them. Thats why I'm posting this.

I'm getting the whole order data when I `console.log(order)`

**Order**

```
{
  paymentType: 'COD',
  status: 'order_placed',
  _id: 60f5829e66e3683b682d45c6,
  customerId: 608d71cce87e0226b0efeb32,
  items: {
    '5eee66c4a27a66807cf2bea5': { item: [Object], qty: 3 },
    '5eee66cfa27a66807cf2bea6': { item: [Object], qty: 2 },
    '5eee6717a27a66807cf2bea8': { item: [Object], qty: 2 },
    '5eee6671a27a66807cf2be10': { item: [Object], qty: 1 },
    '5eee66a5a27a66807cf2bea4': { item: [Object], qty: 2 }
  },
  phone: '07123567897',
  address: 'New address',
  createdAt: 2021-07-19T13:48:14.792Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-07-19T13:48:14.792Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

And **item** are inside **items** which looks something like this when I do `console.log(order.items)`

```
{
  '5eee66c4a27a66807cf2bea5': {
    item: {
      _id: '5eee66c4a27a66807cf2bea5',
      name: 'Chocoholick Delight',
      image: 'Chocoholick Delight.jpg',
      price: 399,
      size: '1 pound',
      description: 'Cocoholics Delight is a delicious cake',
      categoryId: '60d7ea88fa019788bf588bd9'
    },
    qty: 3
  },
  '5eee66cfa27a66807cf2bea6': {
    item: {
      _id: '5eee66cfa27a66807cf2bea6',
      name: 'Elite Happiness',
      image: 'Elite Happiness.jpg',
      price: 499,
      size: '1 pound',
      description: 'Bombastic choco filled creaminess designed with mouth-watering Rochers on top.',
      categoryId: '60d80198f84f2a96ffd9012b'
    },
    qty: 2
  },
```

Now I want to get the **name** which is inside the **item**.

When I do `console.log(order.items.id)` I get `undefined`.
How can I access the name.

If you notice Every **items** have **id** which is same as **item** id. I'm confused there that how to get inside that **items** **id**.

*Thank you for looking us the question.*

Comment: none of the data is JSON?

Comment: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: Loop over `Object.values(order.items)`